# A variable of a Named Range (Excel) in a Userform gives me an error

Tags: vba, excel, variables, named-ranges

I am very new to Excel-VBA (any kind of programming actually) and I am looking for help.

I am trying to make a variable of a Named Range in a Userform (Excel-VBA), but when I try to use the macro with the created variable I receive an error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

How to reproduce:

1) Make a Userform with a label (named test1 in my code).

2) Make Module for the macro.

Here is the code for the Userform and the Module.

The Userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wsTest As Worksheet
Dim rnTest As Range

Set wsTest = Sheets("Test")
MsgBox wsTest.Name

Set rnTest = wsTest.Range("NamedRange")
MsgBox rnTest.Name

Me.Test1.Caption = Format(wsTest.Range("rnTest")(1).Value, "$#,##0")

End Sub
```

And the Module

```
Sub NR_Test()

UserForm1.Show False

End Sub
```

The variable 'wsTest' works. I know this because when I enter the Named Range-name that I see in the Name Manager (NamedRange), the Macro works.

I have searched Stackoverflow and other resources to look for a solution. Most posts tell me I need to use "Set" to make a variable from a range, but unfortunately that is not enough. I am missing some vital piece and I can't put my finger on it.

Any help would be very much appreciated. If there are any question, please don't hesitate to ask.

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: Well asked question btw - great start.

Comment: @brettdj seconded, nice to see a good first question in the vba arena.

Comment: Thank you both for the compliment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Format(wsTest.Range("rnTest")(1).Value, "$#,##0")
```

To

```
Format(rnTest(1).Value, "$#,##0")
```

`rnTest` is the name of the range object you are targeting, but when you pass it in quotation marks within the `Range()` method it is treated as a literal string. Unless you also have a named range called "rnTest" this will always fail.

As you can see from the above example, you can now access the `rnTest` object directly, as the reference has been **Set** earlier. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! If I understand you correctly I was not calling upon the new variable at all. I was talking directly to a sheet and was asking for a Named Range that was not there. 

This concludes a nice first quest :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was explaining - glad you understood the concept, shouldn't take you long to pick up VBA at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should able to cut this code down to just this presuming the range name is global, i.e. you don't need to work with the worksheet.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim rnTest As Range
Set rnTest = Range("NamedRange")
Me.Test1.Caption = Format(rnTest.Cells(1).Value, "$#,##0")
End Sub
```

Comment: Or even `Test1.Caption = Format([NamedRange].Cells(1), "$#,##0")`

Comment: I cut out the variable to point to the worksheet. For now I am working with global Named Ranges. I did not even know you were able to make localised Named Ranges specific to sheets. Thanks for the helpfull tip.